# Custom onClick Behavior For Reusable Blaze Component

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have the following **reusable component** in my Meteor app:

```html
<template name="action_button">
    <div class="action-button-container pull-right">
        <div class="btn btn-danger action-button js-action-button" title="{{this.buttonTitle}}">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{this.buttonIcon}}"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="action-button-title">{{this.buttonTitle}}</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```javascript
Template.action_button.events({
    'click .js-action-button': function(e, tmpl) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // ?
    }
});
```

Instantiated as follows:

```html
<template name="my_main_template">
    ...

    {{# action_button buttonTitle="save" buttonIcon="ok" }} {{/ action_button}}

    ...
</template>
```

**What would be the best way to add custom onClick behavior to instances of this button?**